# Comma placement between two clauses

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Based on my research, #2 is most correct, with two independent clauses separated by the "and". For some reason, a pause after "and" SOUNDS better to me. Is one of these correct and the others incorrect?

> I am a third year student at Blank College Law School, and, as a native of State, I have a special interest in clerking in City.
>
> I am a third year student at Blank College Law School, and as a native of State, I have a special interest in clerking in City.
>
> I am a third year student at Blank College Law School and, as a native of State, I have a special interest in clerking in City.
>
> I am a third year student at Blank College Law School, and as a native of State I have a special interest in clerking in City.

Comment: Increasingly, the *last* option would be favoured today (we tend to dispense with commas that aren't *essential* for comprehension).

Comment: Agreed; the 'extra commas' are largely a matter of style, and thus there is no "correct" version unless following a particular style sheet.

Comment: '3' doesn't sound/look correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

The first option and the last option are correct according to most style books. They recommend that you use a comma before *and/or/etc.* if what follows is an independent clause, a clause with its own subject and predicate and no ellipsis.

If you wish to set off the apposition or subordinate clause *as a native of [state]* with commas, they logically need to be present on both sides, even though more than a few writers do not honour this convention, especially not in informal genres.

Comment: I think your last *not* is superfluous and problematic.

Comment: @tchrist: Do you? I'll admit I often vacillate between *not* and its absence. But I think it is OK, even more precise? See also examples from here: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=especially%20not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cespecially%20not%3B%2Cc0